# How to retrieve custom fields through force IDE?

Tags: metadata, force.com-ide, package.xml

I have retrieved all the custom and standard objects in my force IDE, but I am unable to retrieve Custom Fields. Because of that objects are not deploying in the target org, I have to create manually.

So can you please suggest some solution to retrieve custom fields also through force IDE.

Comment: There is no different file for Fields, they will be part of .oBject file. Can you check your Object file if those fields exists?

Answer (score 0):

Check your src/package.xml file, and make sure your standard objects and custom objects are actually listed in the file:

```
<types>
  <members>*</members>
  <members>Account</members>
  ...
  <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

IF not, you can manually edit this file, or go in to Project Properties > Force.com > Metadata, then "Change" it, click the refresh button (two arrows pointing in a circle), then select the objects you want.

Custom fields appear as part of the CustomObject file, but if your schema is not in sync, you'll often get an empty CustomObject file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" />
```

If it looks like this, then your schema is out of date, and you need to do the refresh again.